# Paso de parametros con Target - Action

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo un boton al que he agregado un Target para que cuando se pulse me llame a una funcion. Necesito pasar atraves del target un parametro extra que no sea el boton pero me tira error al intentar compilar

Si solo paso el boton me deja compilar de esta manera:

Ejemplo:

```
//... codigo

let selector = #selector(self.selectButton(_:))
button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)

//... mas codigo    

func selectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
 // Codigo que se ejecuta cuando pulso boton
}
```

Ejemplo que falla:

```
//... codigo

let selector = #selector(self.selectButton(sender: button, parametro: miObjeto))
button.addTarget(self, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)

//... mas codigo    

func selectButton(sender: UIButton, parametro: Objeto) {
 // Codigo que se ejecuta cuando pulso boton
}
```

Comment: Qué tipo de parametro es? a veces se puede solucionar con otras formas, por ejemplo si fuera numerico, asignas al boton en id el parámetro y como el selector recibe el botón ya puedes obtener el parametro...

Comment: El parametro en este caso no es un numero sino un objeto o diccionario.

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta corta:
No se puede

Explicación:
Al momento de añadir un `#selector` a un `UIButton`, se le esta diciendo al compilador que queremos que se ejecute la función "*pasada*"(1) mediante dicho selector. Esto obliga a que la firma de la función sea alguna de las firmas declaradas en `UIControl`, una de ellas es la que usaste:

```
func selectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
// Codigo que se ejecuta cuando pulso boton
}
```

Donde `sender` es el objeto que manda el mensaje.

Si le agragáramos parámetros a la función, deja de cumplir con la firma (y con todas las de `UIControl`). Por eso que te aparece el error de compilación.

Posibles soluciones:
Depende mucho de lo que quieras lograr, pero una opción es crear una Enumeración que representen los diferentes casos que pueden suceder al oprimir un botón, por ejemplo:

```
enum AccionBotón {
    case actualizar
    case borrar
    case crear
}
```

En el `UIViewController` guardas una variable de tipo `AccionBotón` (a la que llamaré `acción`). El `selector` (o `IBAction`) del botón quedaría así:

```
func selectButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch self.acción {
    case .actualizar:
         //actualizar
    case .borrar:
         //borrar
    case .crear
         //crear
    }
}
```

Otra opción es crear un diccionario de opciones, por ejemplo:

```
var nada = [
    1 : ["a" : "a"],
    2 : ["b" : "b"],
    3 : ["c" : "c"]
]
```

Y en el `selector` (o `IBAction`) del botón:

`let opción = nada[2] //falta un if o algo que decida si queremos 1,2 o 3`

Cualquier opción que eligas, tendrás que guardar todas los posibles "parámetros" en algún lugar (ya sea en el mismo UIViewController u otro lado) y una manera de saber cuál de esos "parámetros" elegir en el selector del botón.

(1) La función en realidad no "se pasa", se resuelve en tiempo de ejecución, de hecho, en las primeras versiones de Swift, el compilador no forzaba que los selectores coincidieran con la firma de las funciones. Si no coincidía, la aplicación se cerraba con un error.

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaracion